# Pronunciation of endings "-tin" and "-tine"

Tags: pronunciation

I am trying to figure out if there is a (kind of) 'correct' rule regarding the pronunciation of endings *-tin* and *-tine*.

I always thought that endings with *-tin* are pronounced as /tɪn/, like for example in *Martin*, *bulletin* or *carotin*.

On the other hand, I considered endings with *-tine* to be basically pronounced as /taɪn/, like for instance in *Valentine*.

But what about words like *quarantine*, *serpentine*, *clandestine*, *libertine* or *philistine*? Also, how would you pronounce *St. Augustine* or *Constantine*, rather as /tɪn/ or /taɪn/?

Do you know if there is a general rule for those endings or is it optional like in the pronunciation of *either*? Thanks for helping me in advance.

Comment: There are *three* "i" sounds there: **quarantine** does not rhyme with **bulletin**. I would pronounce *Augustine* and *Constantine* differently, in the ways you show (respectively). The sequence of words in the line above have various pronunciations too, and I know of no rule, although they could be grouped as nouns and adjectives for their pronunciation.

Comment: Is there a particular dialect that interests you? The conventional British and American pronunciations differ for *serpentine*, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. No, there is no general rule.

I found [this](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/blogs/justin-taylor/should-augustines-name-should-be-pronounced-aw-gus-teen-or-aw-gus-tin/)

I would pronounce *serpentine* and *Philistine* to rhyme with *Valentine,* but *quarantine* and *libertine* to rhyme with *seen.* I say *clan-DES-tin*, but some people would rhyme it with *Valentine.*

Some of these pronunciations must have been influenced by the distinctive pronunciation of Latin that was used by English speakers before the 20th century. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin

Answer (score 1):

> I always thought that endings with -tin are pronounced as /tɪn/, like for example in Martin, bulletin or carotin.

Words that end with **-tin** are usually pronounced as **/tɪn/**.

**Examples:** Martin, bulletin, chitin, Latin etc.

---

Words that end with **-tine** are usually pronounced with **/ʌɪ/** and sometimes with **/iː/**. The vowel before **n** in ***-tine*** constructions either changes to a diphthong (/ʌɪ/) or a long vowel (/iː/). The pronunciation changes because of the addition of the final ***e*** (also called [magic e or silent e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e)). The final e changes the vowel to a diphthong or a long vowel.

#### Examples:

- Hat (/h**æ**t/) + ***e*** -> hate (/h**eɪ**t/)
- Rat (/r**æ**t/) + ***e*** -> rate (/r**eɪ**t/)
- Mate (/m**æ**t/) + ***e*** -> mate (/m**eɪ**t/)

In these examples, the short vowel **/æ/** changes to a diphthong **/eɪ/** because of the addition of *magic **e***.

- Hop (/h**ɒ**p/) + ***e*** -> hope (/h**əʊ**p/) ——— **e** changes **/ɒ/** to **/əʊ/**
- Pip (/p**ɪ**p/) + ***e*** -> pipe (/pʌɪp/) ——— **e** changes **/ɪ/** to **/ʌɪ/**

**Exceptions:**

- Love -> /lʌv/
- Have -> /hæv/
- Above -> /əˈbʌv/
- And words that end with the suffix **[-ive](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ive)** are not affected by *silent/magic e*.
- **Examples:** active, representative, passive etc.

---

> But what about words like quarantine, serpentine, clandestine, libertine or philistine? Also, how would you pronounce St. Augustine or Constantine, rather as /tɪn/ or /taɪn/?

Sadly, they don't follow any pattern.

- Serpentine, Valentine and philistine are pronounced with **/ʌɪ/**.
- [Constantine](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/constantine-i) is pronounced with both **/ʌɪ/** and **/i:/**.
- Quarantine, Augustine, Christine, astatine are pronounced with **/iː/**.
- [Libertine](https://www.lexico.com/definition/libertine) can be pronounced with **/tiːn/**, **/tɪn/** or **/tʌɪn/**.
- Clandestine ends with **e**, yet it's pronounced with **/tɪn/** sound.

> Do you know if there is a general rule for those endings or is it optional like in the pronunciation of either?

There are no 'rules' in English, only guidance. English pronunciations don't follow spellings. You'll just have to learn the pronunciations as you meet them.

To add another layer, American pronunciation of [philistine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Philistine) and [serpentine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serpentine) favors /iː/ , and the "short" i is also, er, routine in brigantine, argentine, levantine, and other words where RP favors /ʌɪ/ — [Choster](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/16052/choster)